# sql search from csv string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

im doing a search page where i have to search multiple fields with a single textbox.
so i will get the search text as a CSV string in my stored procedure

My table is as below

```
ID  Name          age   
5   bob           23    
6   bod.harry     34    
7   charles       44
```

i need a sql query something like this

```
declare @searchtext='bob,harry,charley'
select * from employee where  name like (@searchtext)
```

this query should return both this records (id 5 and 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this way in Stored Procedure,

```
declare @searchtext varchar(1000)

set searchtext ='bob,harry,charley'

declare @filter varchar(2000)

set @filter = '(name LIKE ''%' + replace('bob,harry,charley',',','%'' OR name LIKE ''%') + '%'')'

exec
('
    select *
    from mytab
    where ' + @filter + '
'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use (or adapt) this splitting function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].CsvToList(@SplitOn  char(1), @List varchar(8000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) AS RowNumber
            ,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(ListValue, number+1, CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, ListValue, number+1)-number - 1))) AS ListValue
        FROM (
                 SELECT @SplitOn + @List + @SplitOn AS ListValue
             ) AS InnerQuery
            INNER JOIN master.dbo.spt_values n ON n.Number < LEN(InnerQuery.ListValue)
        WHERE SUBSTRING(ListValue, number, 1) = @SplitOn
        AND n.type = 'P'
);
GO
```

**usage**

```
declare @searchtext='bob,harry,charley'
select DISTINCT * from employee e
JOIN dbo.csvToList(',', @searchtext) f
  ON f.ListValue = e.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to break @searchtext into multiple strings, one for each name. It's doable in TSQL but may be easier in your application code. You can then compare those with your Name field.

Comment: Also the Bulk Insert command can parse csv files, so you could probably use that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken Sql-Server doesn't support Regex. You can use [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). If you are using Entity framework the you could do so.

```
var dc = new MyContext();
var result = dc.employees.Where(x => new [] { "bob", "harry", "charley" }.Contains(x.name));
```

and finally you might construct the following

```
select * from employee where  name in (@Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4)
```

**EDIT**

I highly discourage you to use CSV because of the performance drop (you have to parse your csv) and possibility of errors (consider this csv `Foo,Bar,"Foo with, comma","comma, "" and quote"`)

P.S. If you use table valued parameter when you assign the value use `DataTable` as source.

Answer (score 0):

The above version of [dbo].CsvToList does not work with long input string with a lot of separators. Table spt_values where type='P' has limited number of records.  In my case the function returned 16 rows instead of 66.  Some advise to create your own table with numbers.  I used a different version of this function I copied from other place:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fngCsvToList](@SplitOn char(1), @List varchar(8000))
RETURNS @Result TABLE (ListValue varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20) 
  DECLARE @ind Int 
  IF(@List is not null) 
  BEGIN 
    SET @List = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@List)), CHAR(10), ''),    CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')

        SET @ind = CharIndex(@SplitOn, @List) 
        WHILE @ind > 0 
        BEGIN 
              SET @str = SUBSTRING(@List, 1, @ind-1) 
              SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, @ind+1, LEN(@List)-@ind) 
              INSERT INTO @Result values (LTRIM(RTRIM(@str)))

              SET @ind = CharIndex(',',@List) 
        END 

   SET @str = @List
        INSERT INTO @Result values (LTRIM(RTRIM(@str) ))
  END 
  RETURN 
END
```