# How to return row matching exact string from csv column in sql?

Tags: csv, sql-server-2012

I have table `column` which holds `CSV value`s. eg: 2,3,4,1,13
I want to find specific `string` from the `CSV` and return the `row` matching exact search `string` from `csv`.

**Table:**

```
tbl_A(ID,name,Csv)

ID name   CSV
1  ABC    1,2,13,15
2  PQR    1,4,3,5

@SearchSting=13
```

**Output required:**

```
ID name  CSV
1   ABC  1,2,13,15


select * from tbl_A  where csv like '%@SearchSting%'
```

This will give both rows. :(

Help appreciated!

Comment: Check if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207628/sql-search-from-csv-string

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? The best solution is to fix your broken design.

Comment: its SQLSERVER2012!

Answer (score 2):

Left me start by saying that this is a poor database design and should be avoided.
If possible, you should normalize your database and change that Csv column to a table containing each value in it's own row. 
Further reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

However, if normalizing your database is not an option, you can do this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Csv
FROM tbl_A
WHERE ',' + Csv + ',' LIKE '%,' + @SearchString  + ',%'
```

Comment: hi @Zohar Peled, this solution doesnt work in sqlserver! Previous solution worked...please 'Undo' the answer to previous one...!

Comment: Done. Please let this be a reminder to always use all the relevant tags in your questions. Other databases uses sql standard || for concatenating strings as a_horse_with_no_name rightfully wrote.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't mark the answer as accepted, after you said it works for you?